# How do I find a topic of a website?

Tags: web-services, generics, information-retrieval

I have googled for to find a topic of a site and end with delicious.com but that is not that kind of helpfull..is there any other way to find it?? I am not talking about meta tags or description but catagory of a site...any Ideas??

Comment: From most anyone's point of view, 99.9999% of websites are spam, and the other 0.0001% are a subset unique to that person, with little or no overlap. e.g... all websites are spam

Answer (score 0):

I hate to give an answer to such a sloppy and carelessly written question, but nonetheless...

If you are looking to categorize a specific website, try typing this into google  `site:http://www.google.com/dirhp?hl=en` along with the website you want to categorize and see if you get any results.

If you question is to *find* websites in a certain category, then try [google's categorized directory](http://www.google.com/dirhp?hl=en). It's different than a normal web search.